# Define start and end date of several DataFrames with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have many `DataFrames` which have a different period lengths. I am trying to create a `for loop` to define for all those DataFrames a specific start and end day.

Here is a simple example:

```
df1:
    Dates       ID1 ID2
0   2021-01-01  0   1
1   2021-01-02  0   0
2   2021-01-03  1   0
3   2021-01-04  2   2
4   2021-01-05  1   4
5   2021-01-06  -1  -2

df2:
    Dates       ID1 ID2
0   2021-01-01  0   1
1   2021-01-02  1   2
2   2021-01-03  -1  3
3   2021-01-04  1   -1
4   2021-01-05  4   2
```

I want to define a specific start and end day as:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')
end = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-04')
```

So far, I only figured out how to define the period for one `DataFrame`:

```
df1.loc[(df1['Dates'] >= start) & (df1['Dates'] <= end)]
```

Is there an easy method to loop over all `DataFrames` at the same time to define the start and end dates?

For reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    'ID1':[0,0,1,2,1,-1], 
    'ID2':[1,0,0,2,4,-2]})
df1['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Dates'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'ID1':[0,1,-1,1,4], 
    'ID2':[1,2,3,-1,2]})
df2['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Dates'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your dataframes in a list, and then apply your `loc` formula on all the dataframes in the list using `list` comprehension, and return back a new list of the resulting filtered dataframes:

```
# Create a list with your dataframes
dfs = [df1 , df2]

# Thresholds
start = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')
end = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-04')

# Filter all of them and store back
filtered_dfs = [df.loc[(df['Dates'] >= start) & (df['Dates'] <= end)] for df in dfs]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(filtered_dfs)

[       Dates  ID1  ID2
 1 2021-01-02    0    0
 2 2021-01-03    1    0
 3 2021-01-04    2    2,
        Dates  ID1  ID2
 1 2021-01-02    1    2
 2 2021-01-03   -1    3
 3 2021-01-04    1   -1]


>>> print(dfs)

[       Dates  ID1  ID2
 0 2021-01-01    0    1
 1 2021-01-02    0    0
 2 2021-01-03    1    0
 3 2021-01-04    2    2
 4 2021-01-05    1    4
 5 2021-01-06   -1   -2,
        Dates  ID1  ID2
 0 2021-01-01    0    1
 1 2021-01-02    1    2
 2 2021-01-03   -1    3
 3 2021-01-04    1   -1
 4 2021-01-05    4    2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Because I have many datasets, is it also possible to directly get the individual datasets and not all combined in filtered_dfs? Otherwise I have to sub-select all again from filtered_dfs.

Comment: To use a for loop though you will need to have them at one place. Otherwise how would you loop over them? Perhaps you can use an approach like the above, and then break up the list (or dictionary) of dataframes into individual objects?

Comment: Okey I see, thanks

Comment: I personally prefer to store dataframes in a dictionary, as with names as keys, so that I can then reference them using their name ```df_dict[df1]``` refers to ```df1```, ```df_dict[df2]``` refers to ```df2``` and so on.